# Resetting apache, php for mac osx el capitan

Tags: php, apache, terminal, reset

I'm new to web development, and have recently been following tutorials on how to set up a local development environment.  After properly setting up apache with $sudo apachectl start in the terminal, I had localhost saying "it works."

After fiddling around with the everything and possibly some files in /library/webserver/documents/, I can no longer get localhost to work.  It now says "Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server."

How can I reset apache and php to get localhost back up and running/ can I reset my terminal to its default setting?

I'd like to reset everything so I can go back and properly set up apache, mysql, and php.

Help is much appreciated and needed!

Comment: don't reset / goback try to find solution that fix. this the way you'll learn more.

Comment: Yes I've been doing this for a while and can't seem to find it.  It would be easier to reset and then go through the process again with a clean slate.